# Cannot install aptana on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana3

When I try to install Aptana Studio on eclipse it says

```
Could not find http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install
```

I went to Help -> install new software -> http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

I am using eclipse oxygen standard version

Comment: I guess that is the download link now: http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html#

Comment: nope it's not working

Comment: If you go to this website, select ```Eclipse Plug-in Version``` and select you os and architecture it doesn´t download you the right version?

Comment: When I go there it's just give me steps to download it from eclipse with the link I pasted

Answer (score 2):

You are using an outdated URL. According to the [Eclipse Marketplace, the update site URL for Aptana Studio 3](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aptana-studio-3) is:

```
http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/rc/
```